# How to set up / mock a session within jUnit test with Play 2.4 (Java)?

Tags: java, session, cookies, junit, playframework-2.4

How to set up / mock session within jUnit tests using [WithServer](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.4.x/JavaFunctionalTest#Testing-with-a-server) with Play 2.4 & Java?

Kind of best way would be to be able to do something like:

```
@Before
public void setSession() {
    storeSession("user", "user@foobar.com");
}
```

So far I've ended up with the following choices:

- Rewrite the tests to test controllers with [WithApplication](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.4.x/JavaTest#Unit-testing-controllers)

  - I suppose there should be some way to work with the session.
- Construct the session cookie by hand to be used with WS.

Are there any other choices or would there be example somewhere how to construct the session cookie by hand?

By-hand-constructed cookie could be used like:

```
@Test
public void testMyFoobar() {
    // ... test setup
    String cookie = "..."; // TODO generate session cookie with e.g. user=user@foobar.com
    WSResponse response = WS.url("/myroute?param=123...").setHeader("PLAY_COOKIE", cookie).get().get(timeout);
    // ... check the response content etc.
}
```

Comment: Can you post a code example of what you want to test?

Comment: Added some examples, hope that they clarify

Comment: Is right that you want to create integration tests with Selenium WebDriver? Or do you want to create Unittests without a running server?

Comment: Actually, I wanted to have kind of an integration test for a JSON API. Anyway, for the particular case I ended up changing the tests to access a bit lower level straight to Java classes, without HTTP layer in the middle (that was more sensible for my particular case)

Comment: For constructing the session cookie by hand, Session.encodeAsCookie could be a starting point, see e.g. https://github.com/playframework/playframework/blob/2.4.2/framework/src/play/src/main/scala/play/api/mvc/Http.scala#L555 (would required some Java<->Scala conversion etc)

Comment: You might want to check out [REST-assured](https://github.com/jayway/rest-assured). I use it a lot, e.g. https://github.com/schaloner/deadbolt-2-java/blob/master/test-app/test/be/objectify/deadbolt/java/test/controllers/subject/SubjectPresentControllerConstraintsTest.java